# Ember app use addon installed as transitive dependency

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Can an Ember app use an addon that is installed as a transitive dependency? I have a local Ember addon that lists `ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill` as a `dependency` in `package.json`. When I install the addon into an Ember app using `ember install path/to/addon`, I'm unable to use `ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Wow, this bit me, hard. Ember doesn't support transitive dependencies, wtf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An addon could add dependencies as part of it's installation process. This is usually done in the [default blueprint](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#default-blueprint). The default blueprint is a blueprint having the exact same name as the addon. It's automatically run after addon installation by ember-cli. This is the main reason why addons should be installed by `ember install <addon-name>` and not only by adding it as a dependency using npm or yarn.

Ember-cli provides [different methods to add a dependency](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#working-with-dependencies) depending on it's type. As `ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill` is an ember addon, `addAddonsToProject()` should be used for your case. It expects an object having a array with addon names under `packages` key.

For your example the blueprint would look like:

```
// blueprints/your-addon-name/index.js
module.exports = {
  normalizeEntityName() {}, // no-op since we're just adding dependencies

  afterInstall() {
    // Add addons to package.json and run defaultBlueprint
    return this.addAddonsToProject({
      // a packages array defines the addons to install
      packages: [
        // name is the addon name, and target (optional) is the version
        {name: 'ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill'}
      ]
    });
  }
};
```

More information [Working with dependencies chapter](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#working-with-dependencies) of [ember-cli docs](https://ember-cli.com/).